# Buttons sizes are different even when given the same properties and values

Tags: html, css

At the bottom of my page there are 3 buttons. "Send, Save and Cancel" buttons. The Save and Cancel buttons are the same height but the "Send" button is different from the other two. Why is this happening?

I read on another post that said  elements render buttons different from normal buttons so I tried to fix it with the solution given but it didn't work. I also tried removing  element but it still didn't work. Thanks for your help!

Buttons Styles

```
  background-color: #8f81e8;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/justin-nguyen-the-selector/pen/bOOLyQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give static height to all three buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `send` is `input` while other elements are `button`.

Add `border: none;` to your css

Comment: I changed the element to make it a button but still not getting the desired look. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @j_nguyen Did you reset your boder?

Answer (score 0):

You have two different `div`s: `.user-messages` (the left one) and `.settings` the right one.
The left one contains an input, while the right one contains two buttons. So you can either add `border:none` to the left one to make the border disappear and then re-arrange your layout to use a button instead of an input.

**Update**
Wrap the buttons into a seperate `div` below the div of the two pages and do the following:

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px; /* or whatever you want to have */
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: green;">
    <button type="button">A</button>
    <button type="button">B</button>
    <button type="button">C</button>
</div>
```

Is the result of my snippet the desired outcome?

Comment: I updated the HTML to make the input a button and added the  'border:none' but still not getting the desired look.

Comment: No. I'm still seeing different size buttons. I think giving them a defined pixel value fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the `display: flex` on the `settings-btn-box` that is causing it. One solution could look something like this:

```
.settings-btn-box {
    /* display: flex; */
}
.settings-btn-box button {
    width: 49%;   
}
.btn-save {
    /* margin-right: 10px; */
}
.btn-cancel {
    /* margin-left: 10px; */
    float: right;
}
```

Personally, I'm not a big fan of `float`, but since it's the last element in the div it should be fine.